# Task scheduler settings Greyed-Out

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

While setting a repeat timer for a New task,the **taskscheduler settings panel is Greyed-Out** ( Windows10(Pro-64bit)).

How to enable the settings panel ?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this __related page__ here https://superuser.com/questions/1117610/windows-10-task-manager-startup-disable-button-is-greyed-out?rq=1

Comment: @vssher -thnxs for the reply but this seems to be a goof .I will post reply as an  answer .

Answer (score 1):

Task scheduler tasks (even if the task is running) have to edited by **double clicking on the task and making changes in the window which pops up after that** (also they cannot be directly edited  from the properties panel underneath).

[image]

Comment: Or by right-clicking the task and selecting Properties from the context menu. Or by selecting the task and clicking on Properties in the Action Pane at right.